# a flex DividedBox in as3/Flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know of a simple way to implement a DividedBox layout similar to flex, but done through Flash/as3 ?

I would think there would be a library out there for that already, or some resources, but I'm having a hard time googling for it, as it;s either Flex or unrelated content I keep finding.

***EDIT***
just came across yahoo's astra library ([example](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/layout-containers/examples/FeedReader/FeedReader.html))
I'm going to have a look at it, any other suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/DividedBox.html

You can always use AS3 to create a dividedbox and use it like any other component.

Eg,

```
var myDivBox:DividedBox = new DividedBox();
parentContainer.addChild(myDivBox);
var panelLeft:Panel = new Panel();
//do some changes inside the panel e.g pick a color
var panelRight:Panel = new Pane();
//do some changes inside the panel e.g pick a different  color
myDivBox.addChild(panelLeft);
myDivBox.addChild(panelRight);
```

The above code is equivalen to

```
<mx:DividedBox direction="horizontal" width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Panel id="panelLeft" title="Panel 1" width="25%" height="100%" backgroundColor="0xCCCCCC">
                </mx:Panel>
                <mx:Panel id="PanelRight" title="Panel 2" width="25%" height="100%" backgroundColor="0xCCCCCC">
                </mx:Panel>
            </mx:DividedBox>
```

If you are using flash cs3 or greater, the above code should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across SPAS at http://www.flashapi.org/ giving it a try. the implementation seems much easier than the astra library. The skinning seems easier than with the flex framework library.